# Get location from a stream url in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the redirect url from a stream using php.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
<?php 
$stream = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/178525956/stream?client_id=XXXXXX';
$ch = curl_init($stream);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$url = curl_exec($ch);
echo $url;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Which outputs as a string:

```
{"status":"302 - Found","location":"THE_URL_I_WANT"}
```

So how ould I go about getting the url I want as a variable?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple use `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($url);
$your_url = $data->location;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$data = json_decode($url);
$location = $data["location"];
```